# Non-pageview testing in Google Website Optimiser not showing any results

Tags: javascript, google-website-optimizer

I'm trying to set up a non-pageview test, so that a click on a link is indicated like a conversion in GWO. I did everything like said here: http://support.google.com/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93181
And started the experiment. Control script works fine, traffic is split between variations, but the experiment report in GWO is not showing any visits (0 pageviews/0conversions). It has been 3 days since the experiment began, i'm pretty sured the test had aroung 40-60 visits and conversions (i asked my friends to parcitipate with all the browsers they have). Here's my test experiment: http://www.artmetod.ru/a-b-test/

What am i doing wrong?